# Algebra - amount of speedup

Tags: linear-algebra, percentages

This is quite the simple problem; however it has me going in circles. If I have an execution time of a process as 100 seconds and I speed it up to 70 seconds, does that mean my speed up is denoted as $$1-\frac{\text{original time} - \text{optimized time}}{\text{original time}}$$
or just simply $$\frac{\text{original time}}{\text{optimized time}}$$

Intuitively, the first equation makes more sense to me. But the equation gave in class says the following:
$$\text{performance} = \frac{1}{\text{execution time}}$$
$$\text{speedup(A over B)} = \frac{\text{performance_A}}{\text{performance_B}}$$

implying that the 2nd equation is correct.

Comment: Note: $$1-\left(\frac{x-y}{x}\right)=1-\left(\frac{x}{x}-\frac{y}{x}\right)=1-1+\frac{x}{y}=\frac{x}{y}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you can rearrange your equation to be of the form
$$
1 - \frac{\text{original time} - \text{optimized time}}{\text{original time}} = \frac{\text{optimized time}}{\text{original time}}
$$

Therefore, what you are calculating is the factor by which the secondary processing time is greater/smaller than the initial processing time. What you want to be calculating, however, is the factor by which your initial processing time is greater/smaller than your secondary processing time; i.e. the speedup equation that you have been provided with.